# Not primary ideal having a prime radical

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Find an example of a ring $A$ and an ideal $I$ such that $I$ is not primary but if $fg\in I$, then $\exists n\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $f^{n}\in I $ or $g^{n}\in I$.

Comment: Note: "$\exists n\in \mathbb N$ such that $f^n\in I$ or $g^n\in I$ is [strictly weaker](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/728535/29335) than the normal definition ( that $f\in I$ or $g^n\in I$). So it is not really a primary ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on primary ideals has the following example:
Let $R=k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$, $k$ a field. Take $P=(x,z)$, which is prime. Then $I:=P^2$ is not primary, as $xy\in P^2$, but $x\not\in P^2$ and $y^n\not\in P^2$ for all $n$. However, for all $r_1,r_2\in R$, $r_1 r_2\in P^2\Rightarrow r_1r_2\in P\Rightarrow r_1\in P\text{ or }r_2 \in P\Rightarrow r_1^2\in P^2\text{ or }r_2^2\in P^2$.